# Getting problem while creating OpenLayer circle

Tags: javascript, geometry, openlayers

how to draw a circle in openlayer map? i have tried in diff way, but its not working.. please help me with code. I have used the following code.. but its creating polygon

```
var p1 = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(439000, 114000);
var p2 = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(440000, 115000);
var p3 = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(437000, 116000);
var p4 = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(436000, 115000);
var p5 = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(436500, 113000);
var points = [];
points.push(p1);
points.push(p2);
points.push(p3);
points.push(p4);
points.push(p5);

var linearRing = new OpenLayers.Geometry.LinearRing(points);
var polygonFeature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(linearRing, null, style_green);
vectorLayer.addFeatures([polygonFeature])
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I used [OpenLayers.Geometry.Polygon.createRegularPolygon](http://dev.openlayers.org/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Geometry/Polygon-js.html#OpenLayers.Geometry.Polygon.createRegularPolygon) to do this:

```
var circle = OpenLayers.Geometry.Polygon.createRegularPolygon(
    new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(0, 0),
    1,
    30
);
var feature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(circle);
```

And there is your circle.

Comment: Hi Dude, I have added the following code, but its not working `var vectorLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Vector Layer");
        osMap.addLayer(vectorLayer);
  var circle = OpenLayers.Geometry.Polygon.createRegularPolygon(new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(438760, 114760),1, 30);
  vectorLayer.addFeatures([circle]);`

Comment: @user743148: Well, `circle` is a geometry, you need to make a feature out of it, as you did in your question. I'll update my answer.

Comment: oh, do i need to create the point array? But the radius is enough i think so.. May be i am wrong.. Thanks.. Waiting for you answer.

Comment: @user743148: No, the point array from your question is not used anymore. What `createRegularPolygon` does is essentially the same thing as you tried, just with 30 sides (in my example) instead of just 5 (in your example). It just hides the complexity. The center and the radius is enough information to describe a circle, so you don't need to calculate all the points on the circle line by yourself.